# PostgreSQL query works in pgAdmin but not in Java EclipseLink

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa, eclipselink, jpql

I have a SQL that counts rows per date truncate (months, days, hours). Think a history graph. Query works fine if executed in pgAdmin but fails in Java using EclipseLink.

pgAdmin query:

```
SELECT date_trunc( 'hour', delivered_at ),
       COUNT(date_trunc( 'hour', delivered_at )) AS num 
FROM messages 
WHERE channel_type='EMAIL' 
  AND created_at>='2016-02-28 16:01:08.882' 
  AND created_at<='2016-02-29 16:01:08.882' 
GROUP BY date_trunc( 'hour', delivered_at );
```

JPQL Named query

```
SELECT FUNCTION('date_trunc', 'hour', m.deliveredAt ),
       COUNT(FUNCTION('date_trunc', 'hour', m.deliveredAt )) AS num 
 FROM Message m 
 WHERE m.channelType = :channelType 
   AND m.createdAt >= :fromDate 
   AND m.createdAt <= :toDate 
 GROUP BY FUNCTION('date_trunc', 'hour', m.deliveredAt )
```

EclipseLink debugging log:

```
SELECT date_trunc(?, delivered_at), COUNT(date_trunc(?, delivered_at)) FROM messages 
WHERE (((channel_type = ?) AND (created_at >= ?)) AND (created_at <= ?)) GROUP BY date_trunc(?, delivered_at)
bind => [hour, hour, EMAIL, 2015-12-27 00:00:00.0, 2015-12-27 00:00:00.0, hour]
```

Error:

> ERROR: column "messages.delivered_at" must appear in the GROUP BY
>   clause or be used in an aggregate function   Position: 23

PostgreSQL log:

> 2016-03-01 13:22:08 CET ERROR:  column "messages.delivered_at" must
>   appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function at
>   character 23 2016-03-01 13:22:08 CET STATEMENT:  SELECT date_trunc($1,
>   delivered_at), COUNT(delivered_at) FROM messages WHERE (((channel_type
>   = $2) AND (created_at >= $3)) AND (created_at <= $4)) GROUP BY date_trunc($5, delivered_at) 2016-03-01 13:22:08 CET LOG:  execute
>   S_2: SELECT 1

If I replace the binded variables from EclipseLink logged query and execute it in pgAdmin the query works. What is going on here?

Edit: Just to clarify, it also works using em.createNativeQuery.

Comment: Try turning parameter binding off using a query hint and see if Postgres still has a problem with the statement: https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Querying/Query_Hints#Bind_Parameters  Otherwise, try a different JDBC driver.

Comment: I tried with true and false, no changes. What do you mean different JDBC dirver? I use postgresql jdbc42 driver 9.4.

Comment: Other than parameters being inline, what is the difference between the native SQL query and what EclipseLink is executing according to the log?  What is the query that is executed when you set the eclipselink.jdbc.bind-parameters property to false - does it match the native SQL you pass in to the createNativeQuery?

Comment: @Chris My bad, I used wrong propert name.It works if I set it to false. Please make your comment an answer so I can accept it. Perhaps explain why this happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PostgreSQL can have [trouble](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/FAQ/JPA/PostgreSQL) with resolving parameter binding, which in this case manifests as native SQL with parameters inline work, while JPA generated SQL which defaults to bound parameters fails.

One solution is to turn off parameter binding by passing ["eclipselink.jdbc.bind-parameters"](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.5/jpa/extensions/q_bindparameters.htm) with a value of "false" as either a query hint for the specific query, or as a persistence unit property to turn off parameter binding by default for all queries.

Answer (score 0):

On postgresql, you can use the following syntax

```
GROUP BY 1
```

That means you will group you agregate using the first selected attribute in the SELECT clause. That might be helpful there

Comment: It does not work in JPQL: The identification variable '1' is not following the rules for a Java identifier.